# Inserting HTML in a tooltip Javascript

Tags: javascript

can someone kindly explain to me how I can insert an HTML table in a tooltip using plain javascript and no plugins please?

```
function addingToolTip(element, number)
{
    var tip = $("#tip").hide();
//    $("#tip").html("testing");
    var tipText = "";
    var over = false;
    if(number == 1)
        addTipMouseOver(element.node, "NUMBER");
    else if(number == 2)
        addTipMouseOver(element.node, "NUMBER");
    else if(number == 3)
        addTipMouseOver(element.node, "NUMBER");
    else if(number == 4)
        addTipMouseOver(element.node, "NUMBER");
    else if(number == 5)
        addTipMouseOver(element.node, "NUMBER");
    else if(number == 6)
    {
        tip = $("#tip").hide();
        var html = "<p><b>Testing123</b></p>";
          addTipOnClick(element.node, html);
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if (over){
          tip.css("left", e.clientX+20).css("top", e.clientY+20);
          tip.text(tipText);
        }
    });

    function addTipMouseOver(node, txt){
        $(node).mouseenter(function(){
           tipText = txt;
           tip.fadeIn();
           over = true;
        }).mouseleave(function(){
           tip.fadeOut(200);
           over = false; 
        });
    }

    function addTipOnClick(node, txt){
        $(node).mousedown(function(){
           tipText = txt;
           tip.fadeIn();
           over = true;
        }).mouseup(function(){
            tip.fadeOut(200);
            over = false; 
         });
    }
}
```

This is currently what I have tried so far. I know how to insert normal text. However, now I need to insert an HTML table instead of normal text.

I also am using RAPHAEL JS so I have an image object. When it is click the tooltip with HTML table should pop up.

Comment: can you show what you have for a tooltip so far

Comment: There are countless plugins that could do this for you in a matter of seconds. If you have to use plain JS, please show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Sorry for being very general. I posted the code now. Also, I don't want to use a plugin but I prefer that it is plain simple javascript as shown in my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use plain javascript, I'd go with pure CSS.

```html
<div class="link">Link
    <span class="tooltip">My Tooltip</span>
 </div>
```

```css
.link:hover .tooltip{
    display: block;
}    

.tooltip{
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: However I also forgot to mention that I am using RAPHAEL JS so I have an image object. When it is click the tooltip with HTML table should pop up.

Comment: i have made a small jsfiddle for it, can you post your html part of the code to it? Maybe we can find a solution together. http://jsfiddle.net/n91hsk9m/

Comment: great that's exactly what I wanted @Flo Win :)